# вывод данных в несколько файлов

Tags: python

требуется вывести из separated.txt данные в Y файлов (Y равен количеству строк в separate.txt), чтобы в 1 файл попала 1-ая строка separated.txt, во второй вторая и так далее.

код, выводящий последнюю строку во все файлы:

```
    x = 1
with open('x'+str(x)+'.txt', 'w') as x12:
    with open('separated.txt', 'r') as info:
        lines = info.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            win_id =  line.partition(',')[0]
            win_id = win_id.partition('ID Win:')[-1]
            print(win_id)
            y = len(lines)
        print(y)

x12.close()      

while x !=y:
    with open('winid'+str(x)+'.txt', 'w') as x12:
        x12.write(str(win_id))
    x+=1
    

x12.close()
info.close()
```

вывод:

```
16684-OEM-5355289-86646 
78131-OEM-6679682-56368 
68949-OEM-6087406-52669 
14582-OEM-2353850-24152 
66185-OEM-4348164-93940 
98085-OEM-2390190-64513 
35219-OEM-9026499-23706 
80242-OEM-1430956-39237 
36339-OEM-7367679-58802 
9
```

что пишется во всех 9-ти файлах:
`36339-OEM-7367679-58802`

нужно, чтобы 16684-... попало в 1 файл, 78131... во второй и так далее
я уже пробовал всё запихнуть в with open, но так же не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('separated.txt', 'r') as info:
        lines = info.readlines()
        for x, line in enumerate(lines):
            x +=1
            with open('winid'+str(x)+'.txt', 'w') as x12:
                x12.write(line)
```

Comment: `x += 1` лишнее; и старт в `enumerate` должен быть `1`

Comment: спасибо большое, работает!

Comment: @n1tr0xs а в чём разница/проблема? я просто не слышал про это ещё

Comment: @wesss `x+=1` *автоматически* выполняется в `enumerate`; а про старт: первый файл будет иметь имя `winid0.txt`, а вам, как я понял, нужно `winid1.txt`

Comment: Мне лень было вспоминать, как прописать старт в enumerate) Закостылил слегка, работает же верно)

Comment: @n1tr0xs да, спасибо!

Comment: Ну и f-строка выглядела бы получше, чем `+ str(x) +` всякое )

Comment: @CrazyElf я скопировал код автора и изменил его до минимальной работоспособности)